# I bet you can't find the next number in this sequence

Tags: number-sequence, sequence

Find the next number in this sequence.

> 9, 72, 16, 83, 33, 33, 36, 37, 32, 65, ?

Comment: How much did you bet? Because I think somebody has already found the next number... ;)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Answer

> 98

Reason

> The title is important here: convert each letter A=1 Z=26, and then add them up within a word. For example, B=2, E=5, T=20, so the sum for BET is 27. Finally, reverse this number, so 27 becomes 72. There is one erratum where YOU's sum is 61 and not 51, but I think that's an erratum on the puzzle since this pattern works for every other word. At any rate, the total sum for the word SEQUENCE is 89, so reversing this gives us the **98**, the answer.

Comment: 15,16 rather than 51,61?

Comment: @WeckarE. remember, it's about [Rot13](https://www.rot13.com/)$[$erirefvat gur beqre bs gur qvtvgf.$]$

Comment: Correct. Too bad I didn't say what I bet. Now I reveal my bet: 1 upvote. You win.